# Passing an Array of Numbers via Soap

Tags: c#, xml, web-services, soap

I’m fairly new to programming and I’m in need your help.

I need to pass an array containing numbers to a Web Service using C# and Soap. And have the Sum of these numbers returned to the console application.

I understand that Array within Soap web services do not work well but I need a solution

Comment: 'I understand that array and Soap web services do not work that well', why??? Is this homework?

Comment: I found a quick answer for you.. http://www.google.com/search?q=C%23+passing+array+to+SOAP+web+Service&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla:en-US:official&client=firefox-a

Answer (score 0, accepted):

General info about Webservice: [MSDN Web Services](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t745kdsh%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)

Simple example about how to create SOAP Web services in c#: [WebServices c#](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/308359)

Just change the second example and return an array.

"Via soap" you'll send just an XML document, but if you code the server and the client in c# it's all provided with Visual Studio, you won't even know that you are sending XML, it seems that you are sending objects.

Comment: Hi, I have managed to pass numbers to the webmethod like in the example but when it comes to an array of numbers it returns overload errors.

Comment: -1 for posting obsolete information. ASMX web services should not be used for new development, only WCF.

Comment: Hi Mario, Thanks for the answer after few hours of headscratching I managed to solve the issue, I was trying to pass an entire array. I have tried with an list of ints <int> and worked fine, teh solution is really similar to the one you posted. Thanks!